# C++ Fraction Display Program

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Quick question here, I am writing a program to display a fraction after a numerator and denominator are entered, and display a mixed fraction if the numerator is greater than the denominator. The program seems to be running fine except for when I put the same integer for the numerator and denominator, it always displays a negative number, even if they are both positive.

At this part of the code,

```
if (abs(numerator) == abs(denominator))
{
    if (numerator || denominator < 0)
        cout << "-" << abs(numerator);
    else
        cout << abs(numerator);
}
```

the else statement is not executing even if neither integer is less than 0. It always displays the negative sign. Here is the whole code, I have tried debugging and both numerator and denominator stay positive but it still executes like one of them is less than 0. Any input is greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
short numerator = 0;
short denominator = 0;
short divisor = 0;
short remainder = 0;

cout << "Please enter two integers representing the numerator and denominator of a fraction: \n";

cout << "Please enter the numerator: ";
cin >> numerator;

cout << "\nPlease enter the denominator: ";
cin >> denominator;

cout << endl;

if (abs(numerator) == abs(denominator))
{
    if (numerator || denominator < 0)
        cout << "-" << abs(numerator);
    else
        cout << abs(numerator);
}

else if (denominator == 0)
{
    cout << "\nCannot divide by zero!" << endl;
}

else if (numerator && denominator > 0)
{
    if (numerator < denominator)
        cout << numerator << " / " << denominator << endl;
    else
    {
        divisor = numerator / denominator;
        remainder = numerator % denominator;
        cout << divisor << " + " << remainder << " / " << denominator << endl;
    }

}

else
    if (abs(numerator) < abs(denominator))
        cout << "-" << abs(numerator) << " / " << abs(denominator) << endl;
    else
    {
        divisor = abs(numerator / denominator);
        remainder = abs(numerator % denominator);
        cout << "-" << divisor << " + " << remainder << " / " << abs(denominator) << endl;
    }

return 0;
```

}

Comment: for 
`if (numerator || denominator < 0)`
did you mean 
`if (numerator < 0 || denominator < 0)`
?

Comment: Yes! I thought I could write it that way, brainfart...

Comment: @NasratTakoor is correct, it seems you have a typo there. On another note, in that case you probably are wanting to print 1 or -1 not numerator if I understand your program correctly.

Comment: `if (numerator || denominator < 0)` is equivalent to `if ((numerator != 0) || (denominator < 0))`.

Comment: Even correcting this logic (and other places where you've done it) it would still be incorrect.  One thing you can do is adopt a convention that the numerator always has the correct sign and the denominator is always positive.  So: `if (denominator < 0) { numerator = -numerator; denominator = -denonimator; }` -- that will simplify your logic (and correctly flip sign if both are negative)

Comment: Worked for me to, so technically it is right but the logic can be simplified?

Comment: Try the input -5 -5...

Comment: actually it is wrong, because if both the numerator and denominator are negative (you used inclusive or) then it will still print negative

Comment: Ah I see I hadn't checked two negatives yet

Comment: try -1, -1, it will give you -1, but it should be 1

Comment: Yup your right, fixing it now

Comment: Try [this demo](https://godbolt.org/z/x8bY98E8M) and compare the readability and complexity against your own.  Also try your own program with those test cases and see if it produces the same result.  Note that I did not implement GCD here, since your program doesn't appear to do that either.

Comment: The only problem with that demo is when the numerator is negative, it gives a positive fraction

Comment: I see how it is simpler though, thanks for that.

Comment: I see..  I thought you were using "+" to represent "and".  Anyway, utterly trivial to fix by removing the `abs` call and tweaking the whole number output.  Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Changed this section of code, realized the answer was just 1 or -1 not the value of the integers entered.

```
if (numerator || denominator < 0)
    cout << "-" << abs(numerator);
else
    cout << abs(numerator);
```

To this, checking to see if they are both negative first, then seeing if just either of them is.

```
if (numerator < 0 && denominator < 0)
   cout << "1";
else if (numerator < 0 || denominator < 0)
   cout << "-1";
else
   cout << "1";
```

Here is the whole new code, with 0 in the numerator added.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
short numerator = 0;
short denominator = 0;
short divisor = 0;
short remainder = 0;

cout << "Please enter two integers representing the numerator and denominator of a fraction: \n";

cout << "Please enter the numerator: ";
cin >> numerator;

cout << "\nPlease enter the denominator: ";
cin >> denominator;

cout << endl;

if (abs(numerator) == abs(denominator))
{
    if (numerator < 0 && denominator < 0)
        cout << "1";
    else if (numerator < 0 || denominator < 0)
        cout << "-1" ;
    else
        cout << "1";
}

else if (numerator == 0)
{
    cout << "\n0" << endl;
}

else if (denominator == 0)
{
    cout << "\nCannot divide by zero!" << endl;
}

else if (numerator > 0 && denominator > 0)
{
    if (numerator < denominator)
        cout << numerator << " / " << denominator << endl;
    else
    {
        divisor = numerator / denominator;
        remainder = numerator % denominator;
        if (remainder != 0)
            cout << divisor << " + " << remainder << " / " << denominator << endl;
        else
            cout << divisor << endl;
    }

}

else
    if (abs(numerator) < abs(denominator))
        cout << "-" << abs(numerator) << " / " << abs(denominator) << endl;
    else
    {
        divisor = abs(numerator / denominator);
        remainder = abs(numerator % denominator);
        if (remainder != 0)
            cout << "-" << divisor << " + " << remainder << " / " << abs(denominator) << endl;
        else
            cout << "-" << divisor << endl;
    }

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered already. Maybe the following code will give you an additional idea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <unordered_set>

struct RFraction {
    // We will store reduced fractions. And show numerator and denominator separately 
    int numerator{};
    int denominator{};

    // Contructor will take a fraction, a nominater and denominater, reduce the fraction and mormalize the sign
    RFraction(const int n, const int d) : numerator(std::abs(n)), denominator(std::abs(d)) {
        if (n == 0) denominator = 1;    // All faction with a 0 numerator will get a 1 as denominator
        reduce();                       // Reduce fraction
        if ((n < 0 and d >= 0) or (n >= 0 and d < 0)) numerator = -numerator; // Handle sign uniformly
    }
    // Simple reduce function using standardapproach with gcd
    void reduce() { int gcd = std::gcd(numerator, denominator); numerator /= gcd; denominator /= gcd; }

    // Hash Functor
    struct Hash { size_t operator()(const RFraction& r) const { return std::hash<int>()(r.numerator) ^ std::hash<int>()(r.denominator); } };

    // Equality, basedon fraction and not on a double
    bool operator == (const RFraction& other) const { return numerator == other.numerator and denominator == other.denominator; }

    // Simple output
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const RFraction& f) {
        if (f.denominator == 1) os << f.numerator;
        else os << f.numerator << " / " << f.denominator;
        return os;
    }
};
```